# Splitting variables within dataframe into rows using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've seen similar questions asked here, but I can't seem to get the right output for my data. I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
   pm_code                   sec_pm                    site_no       state
0  010_628 010_228 015_634   2543677 2543677 2543677   010228955     me
```

I'd like to break each cell into multiple rows (split by space) and indexed by state and site_no.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What about site_no? Does that need to be repeated too?

Comment: Sorry, yes that should be the secondary index. Will update.

Comment: @Wen No wen, this is a bit different I think.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Got u  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the first two columns using `str.split` and extract its values.

```
x = df.iloc[:, :2].applymap(str.split).values.tolist()[0]
x = list(zip(*x))
```

Now, take the last two columns and extend them to match the values of the first two columns post split.

```
y = np.repeat(df.iloc[:, -2:].values[:, ::-1], len(x), axis=0)
```

Now, create your dataframe.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(x, index=y, columns=df.columns[:2])
df2    
                pm_code   sec_pm
(me, 10228955)  010_628  2543677
(me, 10228955)  010_228  2543677
(me, 10228955)  015_634  2543677
```

---

If you want a `MultiIndex` instead, you'd need to call `pd.MultiIndex`:

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/45946551/4909087
df2 = pd.DataFrame(x, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(y.T), columns=df.columns[:2])
df2
             pm_code   sec_pm
me 10228955  010_628  2543677
   10228955  010_228  2543677
   10228955  015_634  2543677
```

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1**
`set_index` and `pd.Series.str.split`
AKA, Rubik's Cubing

```
df.set_index(
    ['state', 'site_no']
).stack().str.split(expand=True).stack().unstack(-2)

                  pm_code   sec_pm
state site_no                     
me    10228955 0  010_628  2543677
               1  010_228  2543677
               2  015_634  2543677
```

---

**Option 2**
Same idea with `pd.Series.str.extractall`

```
df.set_index(
    ['state', 'site_no']
).stack().str.extractall('(\S+)')[0].unstack(-2)

                      pm_code   sec_pm
state site_no  match                  
me    10228955 0      010_628  2543677
               1      010_228  2543677
               2      015_634  2543677
```

Comment: Mhm, an elegant one liner... as usual.

Comment: @Vaishali it's a convenient way to use `pd.Series` methods and get back to a dataframe.  However, it's often expensive to swap back and forth.

Comment: @Wen you can even do `unstack([-3, -1])` to do level swapping and unstacking at once.

Comment: @piRSquared Just like open a new gate for me ~ I am looking into it right now , Thank you !!!