# Create MultiIndexed dataframe through constructor

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Given two arrays:

```
x
[('010_628', '2543677'), ('010_228', '2543677'), ('015_634', '2543677')]

y 
array([['me', 10228955],
       ['me', 10228955],
       ['me', 10228955]], dtype=object)
```

Currently, this code gets me a dataframe with a flat index of tuples:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(x, index=y, columns=['pm_code',   'sec_pm'])
df
                pm_code   sec_pm
(me, 10228955)  010_628  2543677
(me, 10228955)  010_228  2543677
(me, 10228955)  015_634  2543677
```

How can I instead create a `MultiIndex` dataframe that looks like this?

```
                  pm_code   sec_pm
state site_no                     
me    10228955   010_628  2543677
                 010_228  2543677
                 015_634  2543677
```

I've tried using `pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples` but I'm not able to get this right. Thanks for the help.

---

**Appendix: *Performance Comparisons***

### Small

```
# unutbu #1
%timeit pd.DataFrame(x, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(y.T), columns=['pm_code',   'sec_pm'])
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.25 ms per loop

# unutbu #2
%timeit pd.DataFrame(x, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(y.tolist()), columns=['pm_code',   'sec_pm'])
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.47 ms per loop

# piRSquared
%timeit pd.DataFrame(x, index=y.T.tolist(), columns=['pm_code', 'sec_pm'])
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.41 ms per loop

# Andrew L
%timeit pd.DataFrame(x, index=[y[:,0], y[:,1]], columns=['pm_code',   'sec_pm'])
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.29 ms per loop
```

### Large

```
x2 = np.repeat(x, 10000, 0)
y2 = np.repeat(x, 10000, 0)

# unutbu #1
%timeit pd.DataFrame(x2, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(y2.T), columns=['pm_code',   'sec_pm'])
100 loops, best of 3: 17.3 ms per loop

# unutbu #2
%timeit pd.DataFrame(x2, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(y2.tolist()), columns=['pm_code',   'sec_pm'])
10 loops, best of 3: 30.5 ms per loop

# piRSquared
%timeit pd.DataFrame(x2, index=y2.T.tolist(), columns=['pm_code', 'sec_pm'])
10 loops, best of 3: 37.2 ms per loop

# Andrew L
%timeit pd.DataFrame(x2, index=[y2[:,0], y2[:,1]], columns=['pm_code',   'sec_pm'])
100 loops, best of 3: 22 ms per loop
```

---

<sub>Data from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45946126/4909087).</sub>

Comment: Appreciate the performance comparison!

Comment: @AndrewL I +1'd your answer. It was nice and elegant. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(y.T)`:

```
In [53]: pd.DataFrame(x, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(y.T), columns=['pm_code',   'sec_pm'])
Out[53]: 
             pm_code   sec_pm
me 10228955  010_628  2543677
   10228955  010_228  2543677
   10228955  015_634  2543677
```

or `pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(y.tolist())`:

```
In [54]: pd.DataFrame(x, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(y.tolist()), columns=['pm_code',   'sec_pm'])
Out[54]: 
             pm_code   sec_pm
me 10228955  010_628  2543677
   10228955  010_228  2543677
   10228955  015_634  2543677
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: I think piRSquared suggests a [better option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45946837/190597).

Comment: I see. I generally dislike jockeying between answers, but if you genuinely feel his answer is better, I'll do a little testing, publish some results, and act accordingly. Thanks for being a fair sport.

Answer (score 2):

You can also slice your arrays and pass to `index`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(x, index=[y[:,0], y[:,1]], columns=['pm_code',   'sec_pm'])

df
             pm_code   sec_pm
me 10228955  010_628  2543677
   10228955  010_228  2543677
   10228955  015_634  2543677
```

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**
If you pass a list of arrays like things, the constructor knows what to do with it.

```
pd.DataFrame(x, index=y.T.tolist(), columns=['pm_code', 'sec_pm'])

    pm_code   sec_pm
me 10228955  010_628  2543677
   10228955  010_228  2543677
   10228955  015_634  2543677
```